# Template type deduction

Tags: c++, type-deduction

I have come across `class = std::enbale_if<condition, type>::type` couple times in template parameter list, I know what `std::enable_if<B,T>::type` does but not sure what `class =` does ? I mean I know `class type_name = type` but why there is no type name in `class =` ? when would I use it ?

Edit: This example from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html)

```
template <class T, class U, class = typename enable_if
          <is_lvalue_reference<T>::value ? is_lvalue_reference<U>::value : true>::type>
inline T&& forward(U&& u)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(u);
}
```

Comment: It is a compilation error, this is what it is. Compilation error aside, this is simply an unnamed template parameter.

Comment: Post a sample please so we can address it more directly

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) (substitution failure is not an error). Below are two examples, where constraints are put on struct and class to disallow instantiations with types that would not be correct.

> but not sure what class = does ? I mean I know class type_name = type but why there is no type name in class = ? when would I use it ?

This is an unnamed template parameter type, you could give it a name but its not needed as this parameter is only used during overload resoultion (to remove non valid candidates). Actually giving it a name might show warnings.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25162a3eb107943f

```
// Allow only T to be floating type (!! actually static_assert would be preferred here)
template<class T,
         class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
struct foo {

};

template <class T,
          class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
bool is_even(T i) {return !bool(i%2);}

int main()
{
  // foo<int> f;  //error
  foo<float> f;   //ok

  //is_even(1.1); //error
  is_even(1); //ok

  return 0;
}
```

[edit]

I must say above examples are not the best, and using static_assert would be recomended as it allows to generate informative error messages. SFINAE should not be used for parameter validation but rather for selecting another implementation depending on provided types.

Answer (score 2):

It's an unnamed template type parameter.  Just like you can leave out the variable name in unused function parameters, you can leave out the parameter name in unreferenced template parameters.

In the specific case of `std::enable_if<...>::type`, this is used solely for SFINAE purposes.  Specifically, if the boolean in the `enable_if` is false, template parameter deduction will fail.